# FTP proxying with ftplib in Python

Tags: python, ftplib

I am trying to connect to an ftp site using an ftp proxy from Python, using the ftplib module.

When I do manually it from the command line, it works:

```
$ ftp ftpproxy.services
Connected to ftpproxy.services 
Name (ftpproxy.services:myaccount): myuser
230- user myuser logged in.
230 [002-0024] Specify Remote Destination with: quote site hostname
Remote system type is UNIX.
ftp> quote site mysite.com
220-(    [002-0059] Firewall connected to mysite.com (192.x.x.x).)
220-(220 ProFTPD 1.3.4d Server ready.)
220 [002-0060] login with: user name
```

When using Python 3.5 or Python 2.7.5 it doesn't seems to accept my "quote site mysite.com" command:

```
>>> ftp = FTP( 'ftpproxy.services', user='myuser' )
>>> ftp.set_debuglevel(1)
>>> ftp.sendcmd("quote site mysite.com")
*cmd* 'quote site mysite.com'
*resp* '200 [002-0046] Specify Remote Destination with: quote site hostname'
'200 [002-0046] Specify Remote Destination with: quote site hostname'
```

Others seems to be having no problem with this in the past, see [link](http://www.python-forum.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=14693)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.sys.tandem/06986wHYO_c) I have figured it out.

When using ftplib, you should not use the "quote" in the "quote site mysite.com", so instead of `ftp.sendcmd("quote site mysite.com")`, just use `ftp.sendcmd("site mysite.com")` and then it works.